# Renomear texto de uma string em uma coluna

Tags: r, dataframe

Olá, bom dia!

Tenho um data frame trimestral que está divido por 1º, 2º e 3º mês de cada trimestre, veja:

```
         Trimestre         Variável   Referência temporal
 1º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos    No 1º mês                   
 1º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos    No 1º mês                      
 1º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos    No 1º mês                      
 1º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos    No 1º mês                      
 1º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos    No 1º mês                      
 1º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos    No 1º mês 
 1º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos    No 2º mês
 1º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos    No 2º mês
 2º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos    No 1º mês  
 2º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos    No 1º mês 
 2º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos    No 1º mês 
 2º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos    No 1º mês
 2º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos    No 2º mês  
 2º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos    No 2º mês
```

Quero renomear na coluna Referência temporal por meses do ano de acordo com o trimestre, então quero que meu data frame fique assim:

```
          Trimestre         Variável   Referência temporal
 1º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos    Janeiro                   
 1º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos    Janeiro                     
 1º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos    Janeiro                      
 1º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos    Janeiro                       
 1º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos    Janeiro                        
 1º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos    Janeiro   
 1º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos    Fevereiro  
 1º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos    Fevereiro
 2º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos    Abril
 2º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos    Abril
 2º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos    Abril
 2º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos    Abril  
 2º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos    Maio  
 2º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos    Maio
```

Veja que o 1º mês do 1º trimestre é Janeiro, 2º mês do 1º trimestre é Fevereiro, e assim por diante...

Existe alguma forma de renomear essas strings diretamente? Pois, meu data frame é bem grande e seria impossível renomear linha por linha.

Resultado de dput(head(tabela1092):

```
> dput(head(tabela1092))
structure(list(Trimestre = c("1º trimestre 2007", "1º trimestre 2007", 
"1º trimestre 2007", "1º trimestre 2007", "1º trimestre 2007", 
"1º trimestre 2007"), Variável = c("Animais abatidos", "Animais abatidos", 
"Animais abatidos", "Animais abatidos", "Animais abatidos", "Animais abatidos"
), `Referência temporal (Código)` = c("115233", "115233", "115233", 
"115233", "115233", "115233"), `Referência temporal` = c("No 1º mês", 
"No 1º mês", "No 1º mês", "No 1º mês", "No 1º mês", "No 1º mês"
), `Tipo de rebanho bovino` = c("Bois", "Bois", "Bois", "Bois", 
"Bois", "Bois"), `Tipo de inspeção` = c("Total", "Total", "Total", 
"Total", "Total", "Total"), `Unidade da Federação` = c("Rondônia", 
"Acre", "Amazonas", "Roraima", "Pará", "Amapá"), `Unidade de Medida` = c("Cabeças", 
"Cabeças", "Cabeças", "Cabeças", "Cabeças", "Cabeças"), Valor = c(83979, 
17709, 5982, NA, 111030, NA)), row.names = 2:7, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: vc quer renomear a coluna Referência temporal pela coluna trimestre?
Por favor, coloque o resultado de dput(head(dados)) na pergunta, para que seja mais fácil elaborar a resposta

Answer (score 2):

Uma das formas de você fazer isso é utilizando a função `ifelse` juntamente com o operador lógico `&` e com o subset de strings a apartir de `substr` (para que não fique dependente do ano):

```
dados$referencia.temporal <- ifelse(substr(dados$Trimestre,1,1)=="1" & substr(dados$`Referência temporal`,4,4)=="1", "Janeiro",
                                    ifelse(substr(dados$Trimestre,1,1)=="1" & substr(dados$`Referência temporal`,4,4)=="2", "Fevereiro",
                                           ifelse(substr(dados$Trimestre,1,1)=="1" & substr(dados$`Referência temporal`,4,4)=='3', "Março",
                                                  ifelse(substr(dados$Trimestre,1,1)=="2" & substr(dados$`Referência temporal`,4,4)=="1", "Abril",
                                                         ifelse(substr(dados$Trimestre,1,1)=="2" & substr(dados$`Referência temporal`,4,4)=="2", "Maio",
                                                                ifelse(substr(dados$Trimestre,1,1)=="2" & substr(dados$`Referência temporal`,4,4)=='3', "Junho",
                                                                       ifelse(substr(dados$Trimestre,1,1)=="3" & substr(dados$`Referência temporal`,4,4)=="1", "Julho",
                                                                              ifelse(substr(dados$Trimestre,1,1)=="3" & substr(dados$`Referência temporal`,4,4)=="2", "Agosto",
                                                                                     ifelse(substr(dados$Trimestre,1,1)=="3" & substr(dados$`Referência temporal`,4,4)=='3', "Setembro",
                                                                                            ifelse(substr(dados$Trimestre,1,1)=="4" & substr(dados$`Referência temporal`,4,4)=="1", "Outubro",
                                                                                                   ifelse(substr(dados$Trimestre,1,1)=="4" & substr(dados$`Referência temporal`,4,4)=="2", "Novembro",
                                                                                                          ifelse(substr(dados$Trimestre,1,1)=="4" & substr(dados$`Referência temporal`,4,4)=='3', "Dezembro","Erro"))))))))))))
```

Com isso, eu consigo combinar o valor das duas colunas.
Outra forma de se fazer isso seria através de um `left join` a partir da função `merge` por exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que o código abaixo faz o que pede.
Note que os dados do `dput` não têm a mesma estrutura que as tabelas da pergunta. Vou usar os dados do `dput` e criar uma tabela como o resultado esperado da pergunta, só com 3 colunas.

```
trm <- gsub("(^[[:digit:]]+).*", "\\1", tabela1092[[1]])
trm <- as.numeric(trm)

mes <- gsub("[^[:digit:]]+", "", tabela1092[[4]])
mes <- as.numeric(mes)

nomes.meses <- c("Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março",
                 "Abril", "Maio", "Junho",
                 "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro",
                 "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro")

result <- tabela1092[c(1, 2, 4)]
result[[3]] <- nomes.meses[mes + 3*(trm - 1)]

result
#          Trimestre         Variável Referência temporal
#2 1º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos             Janeiro
#3 1º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos             Janeiro
#4 1º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos             Janeiro
#5 1º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos             Janeiro
#6 1º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos             Janeiro
#7 1º trimestre 2007 Animais abatidos             Janeiro
```

Comment: que legal! Em termos de eficiência computacional, será que a sua é melhor?

Comment: @GuilhermeParreira Não sei, o `gsub` é lento mas a indexação é rápida. E o `ifelse` também é lento. Como tem mais `ifelse` que `gsub`, talvez a minha seja mais eficiente mas só testando.

Comment: Obrigada pessoal!!! As duas soluções deram super certo.